# I can't find my play button in the Timeline, just the left half of it is visible on the right side of the header

Tags: timeline

So I had it a view times, that I was missing my play button in the Timeline. I searched the Internet but couldn't find help yet.
The bar with the play and pause symbols isn't completely gone. The left part is visible in the left corner of the header but I can't access the other half, as shown in the picture. I tried scrolling. It could be a bug, but maybe it's my fault.
I use Blender 2.92. When I open a new project it's normal again but when I load the previous  file again it's still there. I can start the animation by hitting spacebar.
In need help.

[image: Half of the play/pause bar is missing(scrolling does not work)]

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to perform a factory reset (File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings)

Comment: move your cursor to the right edge until the cursor changes to two arrows. Then hold the left mouse button and drag to right. Tadaaa....is will appear magically.

Comment: How did you try scrolling? With the scrollbar? This is only for the timeline. Get your mouse pointer over the menu bar and scroll with the mousewheel. Usually menu items "disappear" if the window is too narrow to display them all.